# Notation of derivative in 2 forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider $G(x)=H'(x)^T H(x)$ with $H: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

Therefore $G'$ would be : $$G'(x)= H'(x)^T H'(x) + H''(x)^T H(x).$$

I also saw the following notation for this: $$G'(x)= H'(x)^T H'(x) + \left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(H'(x)^T w)\right|_{w=H(x)}.$$

What is the advantage of the second notation?

Comment: I honestly don't see an advantage in this situation. Leibniz's notation often introduces irrelevant letters for denoting the "variable we differentiate with respect to"; and in this case I see no reason for introducing $w$ at all.  This notation can easily get confusing especially if you aren't crystal clear on the difference between functions vs their value when evaluated at a point (this becomes very important for chain rule especially for things like IFT). It is only once you know what you're doing that an advantage with Leibniz's notation is it is sometimes simpler to write

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thank you. Maybe there is an advantage concerning the dimensions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the dimensions. Dimensions of what?

Comment: Of the product of $H''^T H$

Comment: What is $H'$ to begin with?

Comment: I see the second notation as a intermediate step that you could add if you wanted to explain how to get the first line. In words, I would say that
$$ \left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(H'(x)^T w)\right|_{w=H(x)}$$
is telling you to differentiate the first factor only; this leads to the first line. Maybe its less useful when its written in the above abstract form, but might be more useful when an explicit complicated $H$ is used. This could come from a certain formulation of the product rule.